# QuickFIX/J not reading all the repeating groups in FIX message

Tags: scala, quickfix, quickfixj

We are receiving fix messages from WebICE exchange in a text file and our application is reading and parsing them line by line using QuickFixJ. We noticed that in some messages the repeating group fields are not being parsed and upon validating with data dictionary getting error.

```
quickfix.FieldException: Out of order repeating group members, field=326
```

For example in the sample file [data-test.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rlz0uiJ90u-YOjibCwGVMlUjFlf_Cyh4/view?usp=sharing) the first 2 rows parsed successfully but third one fails with the above error message.

Upon investigation I found , in first 2 rows tag 326 comes after tag 9133 but in the third row it comes before that and hence fails in validation. If I adjust data dictionary as per the third one it succeeds but ofcourse the first one starts failing.

This is happening only for few messages for most of the other fix messages are getting validated and parsed quite fine. This is part of the migration project from existing C# application using QuickFix/N to our scala application using QuickFix/J. And its been working fine at the source end (with QuickFIx/N). Is there any difference in both the libraries QuickFIx/J and QuickFIx/N in terms of dealing with group fields ?

To help recreate the issue , I have shared the data file having 3 fix messages as explained above.

Data file : [data-test.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rlz0uiJ90u-YOjibCwGVMlUjFlf_Cyh4/view?usp=sharing)
Data dictionary : [ICE-FIX42.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E0Zi9v_XIscicYg-xrYz3HjsUGhfalL9/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the test code snippet

```
val dd: DataDictionary = new DataDictionary("ICE-FIX42.xml")
val mfile = new File("data-test.csv")
for (line <- Source.fromFile(mfile).getLines) {
    val message = new quickfix.Message(line,dd)
    dd.setCheckUnorderedGroupFields(true)
    dd.validate(message)
    val noOfunderlyings= message.getInt(711)
    println("Number of Underlyings "+noOfunderlyings)
    for(i <- 1 to noOfunderlyings ) {
      val FixGroup: Group = message.getGroup(i, 711)          
      println("UnderlyingSecurityID : " + FixGroup.getString(311))
    }
}
```

Request to fellow SO users , If you can help me with this.

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you check that the fields in the repeating groups on the message are in the same order as in the group in the dictionary? Otherwise you will face the error that you are seeing.

Comment: As explanation: field order is not relevant in root message but in repeating groups it is.

Comment: I checked the first record from the 100 repeating ones and the order looks similar with DD as well as with the successfully parsed message.Is it possible the only few message may be of order among al 100 orders ? Do I need to check all of them ?

Comment: Yes I think you need to check the other records also. Maybe you should print out the sequence number of the problematic messages in your loop and then check them in the file that you parse. Somewhere has to be a difference to the other messages that get parsed fine. And if you say it fetches only 22 repeating groups instead of 100 then I dare to say that the 23rd group is probably the problematic one.

Comment: Hi @ChristophJohn I checked the individual messages and fixed few but it then started failing at the ones which was succeeding earlier. Repeating group field order is not consistent . For example a tag 9013 comes before 326 in most of the message but in some its the other way around and hence it fails. How do you suggest to deal with this ?

Comment: Set `ValidateUnorderedGroupFields` to Y in your config. Or call the according method on your DD. Should be called setValidateUnorderedGroupFields or similar. Sorry no access to the source code at the moment.

Comment: Closest I found was - dd.isCheckUnorderedGroupFields but that has no effect on the outcome. Is there anything to do with the version of quickfix. I am using 2.1.0

Comment: @ChristophJohn Let me know if you find anything on this one please ?

Comment: setCheckUnorderedGroupFields is the one. isCheckUnorderedGroupFields is only to check if the option is enabled. Or did you mean that one?

Comment: Tried that already , No Luck. Error is same. This application is running at source end with QuickFix/N and parsing quite fine.  Is there any difference in both the libraries QuickFIx/J and QuickFIx/N in terms of dealing with repeating group fields ?  I have updated the question with relevant data file and data dictionary if possible could you  try recreating the issue at your end ?

Comment: I have no access to the CSV file...

Comment: And, just saw your source code snippet, you need to do `setCheckUnorderedGroupFields(false)` to disable the validation of the ordering.

Comment: Yes it worked with that, Many Thanks :)

Comment: I've added it as an answer, thanks in advance for accepting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setCheckUnorderedGroupFields(false)` to disable the validation of the ordering in repeating groups. However, this is only a workaround.

I would suggest to approach your counterparty about this because especially in repeating groups the field order is required to follow the message definition, i.e. the order in the data dictionary.

[FIX TagValue encoding spec](https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/tagvalue-online/#field-sequence-within-a-repeating-group)

> **Field sequence within a repeating group**
>
> ...
>
> Fields within repeating groups must be specified in the order that the fields are specified in the message definition.